# jquery multiple character conunting without specificate id

Tags: jquery

I have Jquery characters counting and I need it to echo on the next div after the current input without using id.

So if I have lots of input, I only need to put class=word_count and don't need to create extra id for each one.

http://jsfiddle.net/tbj8y/

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.word_count')
        .on('input keyup keydown focus', function () {
            var maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
            var value = $(this).val();

            if(value.length > 0) {
                $(this).next('div').text((maxlength - $(this).val().length));
            } else {
                $(this).next('div').text(maxlength);
            }   
    });
});

<input type="text" class="word_count" maxLength="100" /><br />
<div></div><br />
<input type="text" class="word_count" maxLength="150" /><br />
<div></div><br />
<textarea class="word_count" maxlength="50"></textarea>
<div></div>
```

Comment: the problem is 3 inputs, only 3rd one works. I need 1st input pass to 1st div, 2nd input pass to 2nd div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` only selects the next direct sibling of the selected element(s), which in this case is a `br` element, you should call the `next` method 2 times.

```
$(this).next().next('div').text((maxlength - $(this).val().length));
```

Or:

```
$(this.nextElementSibling).next('div').text(maxlength - this.value.length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g743q/

Comment: Thx all, I found the problem, because it pass to <br>

Answer (score 3):

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) is only selecting the next sibling if it's a `div` so it's not selecting anything for the `input`s (the next is `<br />`). You can use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to get the next `div`.

Also you can simplify your code a little by precalculating length.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/tbj8y/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.word_count')
        .on('input keyup keydown focus', function () {
            var maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
            var value = $(this).val();
            var length = Math.max(0, maxlength - value.length);
            $(this).nextAll('div').first().text(length);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.nextAll('div').first()`. Problem here is that you have a `<br />` between your div and input element.

You can also use `.nextUntil('div').next()`. So even if you add multiple elements in between these selectors will take care of it. (Provided not another div).

Another way to make it work is avoiding `<br />` tags and use `display:block` for elements

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpf3g/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.word_count')
        .on('input keyup keydown focus', function () {

        var maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length > 0) {
            $(this).nextAll('div').first().text((maxlength - $(this).val().length));
        } else {
            $(this).nextAll('div').first().text(maxlength);
        }
    });
});
```

### [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

### [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)